# Close excel without prompt javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, file-io, save, activexobject

I am trying to close a excel file without prompt, but I am not able to achieve this.

Code:

```
var excelObject = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var workbook = excelObject.Workbooks.Open("path");
//doing something.
workbook.save();
workbook.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set`DisplayAlerts` to `false`. After that it will not prompt.

```
excelObject.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post, but I had a similar problem recently and wanted to add my learnings.

If you are trying to close Excel and want to "properly" close it, you need to first close your **workbook** and don't save (or save) changes. Use this line:

```
Excel.Workbooks("yourfilename.xls").Close(false);
```

or

```
Excel.Workbooks("yourfilename.xls").Close(true);
```

to exit saving changes.

Then, close the actual **application** with this line:

```
Excel.Application.Quit();
```